# Is it okay for normal map to have transparency?

Tags: materials, transparency, normal-map, height-map, pbr

Recently, I was creating a normal map from a transparent height map (both normal map and height map are pinned below). There isn't any shading problems (I'm using Blender) when I'm using a normal map with transparency in it (normal map from the picture below). Is it okay for normal map to have transparency in it? And if it's not, then in what exactly color should I paint these empty transparent areas? Sorry if there's any grammar mistakes – English is just isn't my native language.[image: Normal Map]
[image: Height Map]

Comment: The parts of the map that are not transparent seem to be according to some UV layout... so if the transparent parts don't belong to certain it doesn't matter if they are transparent or not.

Comment: For the record, the transparent areas (which would be shown as perfectly "flat" if they were displayed), would be the color _rgb[0.5, 0.5, 1]_ (or _rgb[128, 128, 255]_).

Comment: Thanks so much guys!